# Adding a prefix to the value of a QR code via a mobile app

Tags: php, android, mysql, ios, qr-code

I've built a ticketing system with PHP & MySQL that generates a barcode for each ticket. The current set up for scanning tickets is a simple web form and a USB barcode scanner. When a barcode is scanned, it submits the barcode's ID to the form and if it matches an ID in the database then the ticket is valid.

I'd now like to be able to scan tickets with a mobile device and am wondering which is the best route to go down. How I envisage it working is the the barcode (or QR code) will have a value like "9783546" and when it's scanned, it will point to a URL like http://www.myscanner.com/checkticket.php?id=9783546

(Perhaps this is not the best solution, if not please let me know.)

Another caveat is that I'd rather not hardcode the URL in to the qrcode itself, as it's liable to change.

I know there are QR code libraries for building scanners for iPhone and Android. Is there an advantage of using one over the other? Is pointing to the url like above the best way to handle this? Is there a prebuilt scanner that allows something like this already?

Apologies for the broad question, some points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was developing simular project. While researching i decided to stop on [this](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/) library.
It is really easy for integrating with your project and it can handle many different types of barcodes.
You should check this library if it supports types of barcodes(QR codes) you needed.

And here you cand find example of integration zxing with android.
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android

But it is steel difficult to scan barcode very fast. You should aim on barcode and after 1-2 seconds it will be scanned. If you want to have fast scanner and if you want scanner to be able to scan barcodes at night time you should consider idea of buing additional device for scanning.

For example like this: http://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Mobile-Barcode-Scanner-for-Cell-Phones-of-Android-wp8-Bluetooth-portable-barcode-reader-data-collection-terminal/509789346.html

It can be easyliy integrated with you android devices through Bluetooth.